# How to attach OutputDataReceived on external process?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I'm trying to start a console application from a powershell script, and then later get the process in a c# program and then attach to the OutputDataReceived event to get the console standard output. My code is like so:

Powershell:

```
    $proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $proc.StartInfo.FileName = $path
    $proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "$args"
    $proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $false
    $proc.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    $proc.Start()
    $proc.BeginErrorReadLine()
    $proc.BeginOutputReadLine()

    $processIdFile = "processId.txt"
    new-item -force -path $processIdFile -value $proc.Id -type file
```

Then, in C# side:

```
private Process GetProcess()
        {
            var processIdFile = Path.Combine(this.MessageQueueDir, "processId.txt");
            var processId = File.ReadAllText(processIdFile).ToInt32().Value;
            var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId, ".");
            return process;
        }
private void ReadOutput()
{
    var proc = GetProcess()
    var _output = new StringBuilder()
    var _error = new StringBuilder()
    proc.OutputDataReceived += CreateLogHandler(_output); // Appends string to stringbuilder on event
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += CreateLogHandler(_error);
    while (true){
       string o = _output.ToString(); // o is always empty string
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, if I copy that process creation code to the c# context, it actually works properly. Perhaps its a Windows issue, where maybe it doesn't let you read output if its created on a different thread? Is there any way around it? My current workaround is to stdout to a text file and read it, but its not 100% safe in all cases.

Edit 1: Also, when starting the process in powershell, I don't get a new console window for the program, whereas, if I start it in c#, a new console window appears for the executable. Not sure if that is relevant or not.

Comment: The power shell is terminating a disposing the output stream so you get nothing.   Try putting a read line at end of power shell so it doesn't terminate.

Comment: Sorry, this was a cut down version. In my full script, I keep a reference to the process and call proc | Wait-Process. Also, tried doing Read-Host to block after creating proc, but still didn't work.

Comment: What are you waiting for?  You have to understand the Windows Streams better (standard input/output).  You are opening your streams from the c# application.  The wait is looking for the steam to close.  If the power shell closes before the c# reads all the data then you are going to loose data.  If the power shell doesn't close your c# waits forever.  So instead the power shell should send a terminating character and c# wait for termination character.  Then c# should close the power shell.

Comment: The process is a long running application that continuously spits out output for the lifetime of the powershell process. Both the powershell and the c# needs to stay open while this process runs.

Comment: Then you need a protocol for sending/receiving data.  You probably have a master/slave application where the client sends commands, server processes the commands, and server sends responses.  So receiving side need to know where the end of the commands/responses are located.  So ASCII strings can be terminated with a end character so receiving end waits for the character before continuing.  If you are sending binary data that include a byte count at beginning of message and then receiving end reads count and wait until all bytes are received.